# cannot resolve symbol AppCompat

Tags: java, android, xml, appcompatactivity

I am trying to add a Splash Screen to an existing mobile app for Android using Android Studio. From everything I have researched, I need to be using AppCompat to do this, but each time I try to add it to my styles.xml file, Android Studio tells me "cannot resolve symbol "AppCompat"". Is there somewhere else I should be adding this prior to the styles page in order to have code accept it? My code is below.

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppCompat">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary"></item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I tried adding it to my AndroidManifest.xml file to no effect, I receive the error "Unknown resource type" in that file.

When I attempted to change my Main file to:
"public class Snake extends AppCompatActivity"
I receive the "Cannot resolve symbol" error again.

I feel like the guides I have read are leaving out some crucial, yet shockingly obvious, step that most people familiar with Android would know quite well. Regretfully, I am still quite new to Android and trying to learn.

Comment: Through some exploration clicking I found I was in "offline mode" in Android Studio. After disabling offline mode the grade was able to fix automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"` in your Gradle dependencies.

You can create a theme with ActionBar and Without ActionBar. If you use a toolbar in your activity probably you should use without action bar theme. Select your theme accordingly.

Create style file like this.

**With ActionBar**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary"></item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

**Without ActionBar**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary"></item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

Now refer theme in the manifest. Hope it will work:)

Comment: I added the line to the dependencies as you suggested, now I am unable to sync my project, getting the error "Gradle Sync Failed: content not allowed in a trailing section". My Gradle file previously had no dependencies section, so I may have added this incorrectly. I added: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}

Comment: Can you post you complete gradle file?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.snake"

        testApplicationId "com.example.android.snake.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}

Comment: You are using compileSdkVersion 26 so update the support version to 26.0.0.  ( compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0')

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it and run.

Comment: Thank you! So obvious, but I did not know to look. This has worked.

Answer (score 1):

So change **AppTheme** parent to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` so styles will be like that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary"></item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

You have these error **cannot resolve symbol AppCompat** because only type AppCompat is not an theme, AppCompat is an symbol inside Themes resouces. So every time you need to set an AppCompat theme you need to type Theme.AppCompat to get the theme AppCompat.